# Find the determinant of a matrix ${\bf A}$

Tags: linear-algebra

${\bf A}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix such that:

- $a_{ij} = n$, if $i \neq j$
- $a_{ii} = i$

Find the determinant of ${\bf A}$.

Comment: I think you need to make another edit, I don't really understand your "n, if i is not equal to j" and the "i, if i=j" Edit: Now I get it.

Comment: So in the case of a $4\times 4$ matrix, you are asking for the determinant of $\begin{bmatrix}1&4&4&4\\4&2&4&4\\4&4&3&4\\4&4&4&4\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @Moo no not really, I think I am doing something wrong because I do not see any pattern

Comment: Hint: Subtract the last row from the first $n-1$ rows.

Answer (score 6):

By subtracting the last row from all the other rows (which doesn't change the determinant) we arrive at a matrix with diagonal entries $1-n,2-n,\dots,-1$ and $n,$ and with zeros above the diagonal. So the determinant is the product of the diagonal entries, which works out to $$(-1)^{n-1} n!$$